# Make div NOT auto stretch to container width

Tags: html, css

My question is simple:

Can you stop a div from auto-stretching to the width of its containing element and have it only stretch horizontally as much as the content inside it forces?

Kind of like the default vertical behavior of divs but applied horizontally. Is this possible?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You'd have to set the `display` property to `inline-block`

```
<div style="display: inline-block">Text</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Actually, `display:inline` will have better browser support, but may not achieve the results you want, it will keep the div in line with the content, a la `<span>`.

There's two types of elements: block, and inline.  Block elements stretch to width and break the line.  Inline stretches to content and stays inline. (!)

`display:inline-block` is getting better support, but the older browsers won't do it.